# Angular UI-Router Multiple Named Views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

### Desired Behavior

I'm using AngularJS and the Angular UI-Router.

1. I want to allow two child states to share a parent state.
2. I want the child states to fill a `ui-view` in the parent state's view with their own view.
3. I want one of the two child states to have three `ui-view`'s in their view, each filled with views.

Attempt at a diagram:

```
Parent: <ui-view>
        filled by
          Child:  <ui-view> <ui-view> <ui-view>
                    filled    filled   filled
```

### Specific Details for My Situation

I have a state called `category-details`.  Inside the view for this abstract state I have an unnamed `ui-view`.  In one of the two child states (`category-details.selected`) I want to use [multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views).

### Current WORKING Strategy

Here is the abstract state.  Very basic, but included for your reference.

```
.state('category-details', {
    abstract: true,
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Category Details'
    },
    templateUrl: "views/category-details.html",
})
```

In the `category-details.selected` state (the state which will have multiple named views), I set the unnamed `ui-view` of `category-details.html` to `category-details-selected.html`:

```
.state('category-details.selected', {
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'views/category-details-selected.html',
            controller: 'CategoryDetailsSelectedCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Inside of the `category-details-selected.html` view I have three named `ui-views`:

```
<div ui-view="firstNamedView"></div>
<div ui-view="secondNamedView"></div>
<div ui-view="thirdNamedView"></div>
```

Finally, I define a state for setting these three `ui-view`'s to meet the third part of my desired behavior:

```
.state('category-details.selected.aspect', {
    url:"/category-details/:selectedCategory",
    views: {
        'firstNamedView': {
            templateUrl: 'views/first-named-view.html',
            controller: 'FirstNamedViewCtrl'
        },
        'secondNamedView': {
            templateUrl: 'views/second-named-view.html',
            controller: 'SecondNamedViewCtrl'
        },
        'thirdNamedView': {
            templateUrl: 'views/third-named-view.html',
            controller: 'ThirdNamedViewCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

### Why My Solution is Awkward and Suboptimal

Adding the `category-details.selected.aspect` state to set constant elements (the three `ui-view`'s) of the `category-details-selected` view is unnecessary.  It forces creating an extra state every time I want multiple named views.

### What I've Tried

I believe I should be able to move the url and views of the `category-details.selected.aspect` state into the `views` component of its parent state (`category-details.selected`).  This would look like:

```
.state('category-details.selected', {
    url:"/category-details/:selectedCategory",
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'views/category-details-selected.html',
            controller: 'CategoryDetailsSelectedCtrl'
        },
        'firstNamedView': {
            templateUrl: 'views/first-named-view.html',
            controller: 'FirstNamedViewCtrl'
        },
        'secondNamedView': {
            templateUrl: 'views/second-named-view.html',
            controller: 'SecondNamedViewCtrl'
        },
        'thirdNamedView': {
            templateUrl: 'views/third-named-view.html',
            controller: 'ThirdNamedViewCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

This resulted in the unnamed `ui-view` being set correctly, but the three named `ui-view`'s were not filled.

Since selecting the three named `ui-view`'s was the problem, I then attempted to select them with `absolute selectors` [described here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views) instead.  This did not fix the problem.  I tried:

```
firstNamedView
firstNamedView@
firstNamedView@category-details.selected
(others of course)
```

### Closing Remarks

Is what I'm imagining possible, is another way better, or is my current method the best?  It boils down to assigning the child `ui-view`s of a parent `ui-view` being set at the same time.  I thought the last sentence was too confusing alone, so I included the entire example.

Please let me know if I can provide any more clarification such as versions.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Abstract states need their own `<ui-view/>` for their children to plug into.

Parent state `category-details` is `abstract` state. Child state will need some reference ui-view to plug that state into. In your I believe the view `/category-details.html` does not any ui-view (as you have mentioned that `category-details-selected.html` contains the ui-view).

Try this:

```
.state('category-details', {
  abstract: true,
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Category Details'
  },
  templateUrl: "views/category-details-selected.html",
})

.state('category-details.selected', {
  url:"/category-details/:selectedCategory",
  views: {       
    'firstNamedView': {
        templateUrl: 'views/first-named-view.html',
        controller: 'FirstNamedViewCtrl'
    },
    'secondNamedView': {
        templateUrl: 'views/second-named-view.html',
        controller: 'SecondNamedViewCtrl'
    },
    'thirdNamedView': {
        templateUrl: 'views/third-named-view.html',
        controller: 'ThirdNamedViewCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Here, we are giving abstract view a template, which has ui-view in it, for child to populate.

Have a look at documentation of [ui-router: Abstract State](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views#abstract-states) for more information.

---

**EDIT**:  I had assumed that `views/category-details.html` does not contain any ui-view. However, it was then pointed out that, `views/views/category-details.html` does have ui-view

This is what works for me:

category-details.html:

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

category-details-selected.html:

```
<div ui-view="firstNamedView"></div>
<div ui-view="secondNamedView"></div>
<div ui-view="thirdNamedView"></div>
```

router:

```
    .state('category-details', {
        abstract: true,
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Category Details'
        },
        templateUrl: "../app/atest/category-details.html",
    })


    .state('category-details.selected', {
        url: "/atest",
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: "../app/atest/category-details-selected.html",
                //   controller: 'approvalsCtrl as vm',
            },
            'firstNamedView@category-details.selected': {
                templateUrl: '../app/atest/first.html',
                //    controller: 'approvalsCtrl as vm',
            },
            'secondNamedView@category-details.selected': {
                templateUrl: '../app/atest/second.html',
                //   controller: 'approvalsCtrl as vm',
            },
            'thirdNamedView@category-details.selected': {
                templateUrl: '../app/atest/third.html',
                //   controller: 'approvalsCtrl as vm',
            }
        }
    })
```

I could see that you have mentioned you tried out using `firstNamedView@category-details.selected`, but it didn't worked for you. The above example is working for me. Check if you `category-details.html` and `category-details-selected.html` view contain proper `ui-view`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Sudarshan_SMD.  I currently include a `ui-view` in the `category-details` view.  This is the view set based on the `category-details.selected` or `category-details.unselected` states.  The `category-details.selected` then holds the view with three `ui-view`s for the child states.  Your solution removes the highest parent and goes from my `parent - child - multiple states` design to `child - multiple states`.  Requirement #1 of my question is not met.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @MattGoodrich I got your point. Have edited the answer with `category-details.html` at parent. The solution that I have provided, works for me.

Comment: I thought I had tried the absolute selector `firstNamedView@category-details.selected` and it did not show any of the child views.  I didn't include it in the SO post to prevent confusion, but I had a very top-level abstract state called `index`.  I just tried `firstNamedView@index.category-details.selected` and it worked.  Thanks for working through this with me and sorry about my silly mistake.